# Is there a way to undo a "close as duplicate" vote?

Tags: support

I went too damn fast on one question:

[Adapter for Olympus SLR lenses on Sony a6000 camera?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/62095/adapter-for-olympus-slr-lenses-on-sony-a6000-camera)

and voted it as a duplicate before I remembered that the Sony A6000 is one of the mirrorless E-mount cameras, not one of the A-mount SLTs. [headdesk]. Is there any way to undo the vote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* retract your own vote. Click on the close link again, and then look at the bottom for the Retract button. Once you do this, you can't re-vote to close, even for a different reason (unfortunately — sometimes I want to change from "unclear" to "duplicate". Oh well.)

This doesn't, I think, pull the question from the close review queue, or cancel your comment, but adding a *new* comment (as you did) probably balances that.

Comment: Heh, my view is different... I had entirely forgotten that.

Comment: JoanneC: The perils of being a mod for too long :)

Comment: This is true, I have the same problem on the other site I frequent.

Comment: Thank you! Vote's been retracted.